# Plot multiple series from the same file

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a data file that looks something like the following:

```
2016-08-16 dogs 12
2016-08-16 cats 9
2016-08-17 cats 4
2016-08-17 mice 42
2016-08-17 dogs 6
```

That is: `date series count`.

Note that the series are not in a consistent order on each day (and might not appear at all).

Further, my input file doesn't have the dates in order either (though I can fix that with `sort` if I *have* to), and some of the dates might be missing (because there are no data points for that day).

I'd like to use **gnuplot** to render this. The X-axis should display the date; the Y-axis should display the count; each series should be its own line, with labels in the legend.

I know how to render each series from a separate file, but the series are not fixed, so I'm looking for something that doesn't require that.

How do I do this?

*Note: I'm using gnuplot 4.4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps one could first transform the input file (`input.txt`) file like so:

```
sort -k2,2 -k1,1 input.txt | \
gawk '{if($2!=prev){if(NR>1){print "\n";}print "date", $2; prev=$2;}print $1,$3}' > input2.txt
```

which in this particular case provides

```
date cats
2016-08-16 9
2016-08-17 4


date dogs
2016-08-16 12
2016-08-17 6


date mice
2016-08-17 42
```

and then plot this multi-dataset file with

```
datafile="input2.txt"
stats datafile

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'

N=int(STATS_blocks)-1
plot for [i=0:N] datafile index i using 1:2 w lp t columnhead(2)
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: The `stats` command doesn't seem to work as shown with gnuplot 4.x (or with 5.0p3 on OSX); I get `bad data on line 1 of file animals`.

Comment: This works, though: `N = system("grep -c ^date " . inputfile)` -- if I also change the range to `for [i=0:N-1]`, obviously.