# Is it possible to plot data with unknown number of series having the series id in the first column

Tags: gnuplot

I have data file containing an unknown numer of data series. In the first column is always the idetifier or the "label" if you want. The column two and three are the x and y values. In this example I have only two series "DHT" and "ENZN" so I expect two lines here.

```
DHT 1129154400000 0.097789886726083
ENZN 1129154400000 1.7894367732558
DHT 1129240800000 0.096329124932664
ENZN 1129240800000 1.8302216569767
DHT 1129500000000 0.099412955385437
ENZN 1129500000000 1.7919858284884
DHT 1129586400000 0.098844881354663
ENZN 1129586400000 1.7817896075581
DHT 1129672800000 0.098520267622792
ENZN 1129672800000 1.840417877907
```

Comment: So what do you want to plot ?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018861/2604213

Comment: indeed this awk solution works ...